# JUnit string comparison

Tags: string, junit

I know how strings are compared and I read online that using:

```
assertEquals(String,String);
```

is safe... However I get following error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<53> but was:<53>
```

In particular I do something like this:

```
assertEquals(totalRecipients.toString(), dataLineCount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataLineCount` doesn't sound like a `String` to me - but I can't say for sure without looking at your code.

Assuming `dataLineCount` is an `int` you would not be calling `assertEquals(String,String)` but `assertEquals(Object,Object)` with a `String` and an `Integer` as arguments (because of autowrapping). And `String` and `Integer` don't compare equal...